# Python Keyboard shortcuts

Tags: python

So, I have a python script running I  the background, and I want it to trigger X function whenever a key combination is pressed. How would I implement that? The problem is that the app will be running in the background, so it won't have focus from the OS.

Comment: The answer to this (if there is one) is very much OS specific.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it basicly has nothing to do with python. That heavily depends on the operating system you're working on.

You can use XLib under Linux (http://python-xlib.sourceforge.net/) or wxPython under Windows (http://wxpython.org/docs/api/wx.Window-class.html#RegisterHotKey)

Another idea would be to hook the system keyboard events (through pyHook) and try to catch any hotkeys.

Comment: Thanks. pyHook looks like the right thing, but it's Windows only. Is there a lib for Mac which does it?

Comment: @user697108: You would need to use PyObjc with http://www.theregister.co.uk/2009/02/24/hotkeys_framework2/

Comment: I think wxPython might not be the right one to suggest for this. Writing a solution via a GUI framework will mean its only useful when the app has focus. The solution has to be operating system hooks (like your XLib suggestion)